# React Native Augmented Reality scanning 3D model

Tags: react-native, augmented-reality

I want to scan an object in real life and convert it as a model for Augmented Reality (AR).
Can I do it with viro?

Any suggestions is welcomed

Comment: hi @keurdange! did u ever find a solution for this?